# Symfony fileupload not workig in Firefox but in Chrome

Tags: php, symfony

Im working on a symfony project to upload abstracts of papers. Im not new to php and I remember having a similar problem in plain php. But I don't quite remember how I solved it. Im trying to upload an pdf, but on submit, the server (symfony build in server) stops taking requests and my only option is to stop the server. Firefox shows that ~700B were transfered (it varies ???), but no response was given by the server. However, after a while I tried the form in Google Chrome and was really surprised when it worked perfectly. 
On shutdown the symfony server somtimes shows an errormessage (there are german parts):

```
shut down, bye! with server callback Mar 30 17:57:25 |eRRORe VER issue with server callback
1merrore"unable to fetch the response from the backend: read tcp 127.0.0.1:53834->127.0.0.1:53811:    wsarecv: 
 Eine vorhandene Verbndene Verbindung werbindung w Verbindung wurde vom ng wurde vom 
 RemS9m="unable to fetch the res  S9m="unable to fetch the response from the backend: read tcp  
 127.0.0.1:53834->127.0.0.1:53811: wsarecv: Eine vorhandene Verbndene 
Verbindung werbindung w Verbindung wurde vom ng wurde vom Remindung w Verbindung wurde vom RMar 30 
17:57:25 |Mar 30 17:57:25 |S1mERRORE VERET (502)
```

Maybe its because somehow the upload is still working, but in chrome it took under an second to upload (10KB) and had no problems.

My code for the Symfony form:

```
    public const paperFileFormID = "paperFile";
    public const signatureFileFormID = "signatureFile";

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(self::paperFileFormID, FileType::class, [
                'label' => "Upload Paper (PDF File)",
                'mapped' => false,
                'constraints' =>
                [
                    new File([
                        'maxSize' => '30000k',
                        'mimeTypes' => [
                            'application/pdf',
                            'application/x-pdf'
                        ],
                        'mimeTypesMessage' => 'please upload a valid PDF document'
                    ])
                ],
            ])->add(self::signatureFileFormID, FileType::class, [
                'label' => "Upload Paper (PDF File)",
                'mapped' => false,
                'constraints' =>
                    [
                        new File([
                            'maxSize' => '2048k',
                            'mimeTypes' => [
                                'application/pdf',
                                'application/x-pdf'
                            ],
                            'mimeTypesMessage' => 'please upload a valid PDF document'
                        ])
                    ],
            ])
            ->add('title', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => "title"
                ]
            ])
            ->add('coauthorEmails', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'coauthor email adresses',
                'required' => false
            ])
            ->add('upload', SubmitType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => PaperAbstract::class
         ]);
    }
```

And the **controler** :

```
        public function uploadAbstract(Request $request, SluggerInterface $slugger){
            $paperAbstract = new PaperAbstract();
            $form = $this->createForm(AbstractUploadType::class, $paperAbstract);
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){

                $paperAbstractData = $form->get(AbstractUploadType::paperFileFormID)->getData();
                $signatureData     = $form->get(AbstractUploadType::signatureFileFormID)->getData();

                $originalAbstractFileName = pathinfo($paperAbstractData->getOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                $originalSignatureFileName = pathinfo($signatureData->getOriginalName(),PATHINFO_FILENAME);

                $safeFilename = $slugger->slug($originalAbstractFileName);
                $newFilename = $safeFilename.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$paperAbstractData->guessExtension();
                $safeFilename = $slugger->slug($originalSignatureFileName);
                $newFilename = $safeFilename.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$signatureData->guessExtension();
                $signatureData->move(
                    $this->getParameter('paperDirectory'),
                    $newFilename
                );

                return new Response("test");

            }

            return $this->render('/full_template/abstract_upload.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
        }
```

Its not ready yet, just for test purpose.
Im working on windows and using the xampp php executable for the build in server.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this or what the problem might be? Im actually out on ideas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem...
It was OneDrive. I tried to upload an file out of the OneDrive folder and it wasn't synced while OneDrive was deactivated. So the connection timed out. In chrome when testing it was luck that the one file was synced out of the directory where I used it...
So a pretty stupid error...